# Неправильный путь к nodejs в bash

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Я только начал разбираться с системами на основе Linux, так что скорее всего вопрос глупый, заранее прошу прощения.

Я установил nvm следуя инструкциям в официальном репозитории на GitHub, в то же время в системе стояла предустановленная версия nodejs. 
Результат команд при выполнении их в терминале:

```bsh
$ command -v nvm #nvm
$ node -v #v12.12.0
$ nodejs -v #v10.15.2
$ which node #/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v12.12.0/bin/node
$ which nodejs #/usr/bin/nodejs
```

Результат выполнения при запуске .sh файла:

```bsh
$ command -v nvm #Вывод отсутствует, команда nvm ему не знакома
$ node -v #v10.15.2
$ nodejs -v #v10.15.2
$ which node #/usr/bin/node
$ which nodejs #/usr/bin/nodejs
```

Погуглив об этом, я пришёл к выводу, что мне нужно изменить ссылку на Ноду:

```
sudo ln -s `which nodejs` /home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v12.12.0/bin/node
```

Однако при выполнении я получаю ошибку: "Не удалось создать символьную ссылку ... Файл существует". 
Собственно вопрос: Как мне изменить место, где bash ищет Ноду? Желательно сделать это так, чтобы при смене активной версии в nvm, bash это понимал.

ОС - Debian 10 (Cinnamon)

**UPD**
Почитал другие темы, понял, что не так с командой, изменил на

```
sudo ln -sfn `which nodejs` /home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v12.12.0/bin/node
which nodejs #/usr/bin/nodejs
```

Ошибка пропала, но команда не делает ничего. Поменял местами аргументы

```
sudo ln -sfn /home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v12.12.0/bin/node `which nodejs`
which nodejs #Вывода нет
```

Стало только хуже

Comment: А зачем вам nodejs? Это устаревшая команда, пользуйтесь node, а системный пакет с нодой вообще снесите

Comment: @AlexeyTen Мне нужен способ запускать .js скрипты при помощи .sh скриптов на той же версии, что доступна в терминале, а будет ли это команда `node` или `nodejs` - не так важно. Сносить системный пакет пробовал, тогда .sh скрипты вообще не понимали ни `node`, ни `nodejs`, в то время как в терминале всё работало отлично

Comment: А скрипты запускаются от того же пользователя?

Comment: nvm вообще позиционируется для разработки.  Если нужна общесистемная нода, то лучше https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md и забыть про смену версии

Comment: Да, от того же. Использую NVM именно что для разработки, но запускать каждый скрипт через терминал - неудобно, а в некоторых случаях обязательно нужен .sh скрипт

Comment: Хм, а как ещё запускать скрипты? Ну в общем вам придётся что-то придумывать. nvm по сути меняет PATH в текущем bash/zsh и вроде запускается только в интерактивном терминате

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не идеальное, но всё же решение:
 1. Удалить папку с Нодой, которую хотим поставить -
 `/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v12.12.0`
 2. Установить эту же Ноду с нуля - `nvm i node 12.12.0`
 3. Выполнить `nvm alias default 12.12.0`
 4. Выполнить `` sudo ln -sfn `which nodejs` /home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v12.12.0/bin/node ``
 5. Для запуска .js файлов в .sh скрипте использовать команду `nodejs`